# Why is Closure Compiler generating different syntax?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

Why does the Closure Compiler generate different code (using *advance* option) for the following two functions:

```
  var function1 = function() {
        return 1 * Math.random();
  };

  window['function1'] = function1;  // export function1

  var function2 = function() {
        return function1() + 1;
  };

  window['function2'] = function2;  // export function2
```

This is the code generated:

```
  function a() {
        return 1 * Math.random();
  }

  window.function1 = a;

  window.function2 = function() {
        return a() + 1;  // call to a() fails in a more complex example
  };
```

Notice that `function1` has been renamed to `a` and `a` is assigned to the global varible `function1`. With `function2` there is no other variable name associated with it. Why?

The reason why I ask is, in the case with my code, the call to `function1` from `function2` fails because the renamed `function1` is not seen as a function call in `function2` but rather the Javascript interpreter thinks that `a()` is a number.

Any insight is appreciated. TIA.

Comment: That's what minifiers do. It's called _function name mangling_, you can probably find it on Google. I use uglifyjs not closure, but there should be an option to turn that feature off. The advance feature AFAIK can cause problems if you don't _write your code for closure_.

Comment: @elclanrs (1) the export is to keep the names from being mangled and (2) either way, why isn't the syntax created consistent?

Comment: No idea, like I said I use uglifyjs to minify/optimize code. You could try it out, it's pretty fast and it's written in JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "a" is a number, most likely it is getting overwritten by something else.  If you aren't using multiple modules, try using the output wrapper option to isolate the globals (There are  other options to isolate globals if you are using multiple modules). Often defining a setter on "windows.a" and setting a break point there will let you know how this overwrite is happening.

Comment: I am using multiple modules and `a` was being overwritten when an uncompiled js file was mistakenly loaded rather than the compiled version, i.e. stupid mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Using ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS, Closure Compiler will remove unused code. Since the only use of `function2` was in the export, the assignment was made directly to the exported name (rather than first to a variable).  `function1` was both exported and used by `function2` so the compiler left the initial named function as it was referenced twice.

As for the failure, we'd need to see your actual code to explain what's happening.

Comment: Up vote. Thanks for answering why Closure genererates the different function declarations.